# Socket communication between C applications running on same machine

Tags: c, sockets

I am using C language and Linux as platform to develop two small applications. The first one, a client, sends a character via socket and the second, a server, reads the message and sends back the same thing that was read.

Once there's a connection established between the applications then the following code is supposed to send and receive the same message 5 times:

code edited:

```
char buf[100];
char message[100];
fd_set readfds, writefds;
int n, rvd;

memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
message[0] = 'a';

inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
printf("client: connecting to,, %s\n", s);

freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

n = sockfd+1;

for (unsigned long i=0; i<5; i++)
{

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);

    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &writefds);

    rvd = select(n, NULL, &writefds, NULL, NULL);

    if (rvd > 0)
    {
        printf("client: writing '%s'\n",message);
        if ((numSent = send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0)) != -1)
        {

            rvd = select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (rvd > 0)
            {
                if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, numSent, 0)) != -1)
                {
                    printf("client: received '%s'\n",buf);
                }
                //timestamp it
                //count successful package sent
            }
            else
            {
                //throw this measurement
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program sends and receives messages successfully twice. When it attempts to send for the thirds time it fails, even though the function select returns a value bigger than 0 (which means that the server is ready to receive data).

When debugging with eclipse the function send() crashes on its third execution and the following message is shown:

**No source available for "send() at 0x7ffff7bcc282"**

View Disassembly... [button]

When I run the server application on a virtual machine everything runs OK though.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did send return each time? Are you checking the return code and errno after each function? Please print those.

Comment: Vital to show definition of `message` and `buf` and how `message` is populated.

Comment: Your code snippet is too short. It's unclear if `writefds` and `readfds` only contain `sockfd` and if so, you can directly use a blocking socket for `send` and `recv` as you use `select` without a timeout anyway. Also you don't show if you set `n` properly or not. Also you print `message` with `%s` but you claim that it's a `char`, so it should be `%c`. As you seem to have no problem with the `printf`, I assume that `message` is either a `char*` or a `const char*`, which will get you into trouble when writing to `buf`, but using the `sizeof(message)` instead of the size of your `buf` variable.

Comment: `sizeof(message)` != `size_t len` of `message`. Better to use `send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0)` to send the number of chars in `message` instead of the `sizeof (char *)`

Comment: @Vality the program just breaks at send(). On Debug mode a window is opened in eclipse with the message I mentioned.

Comment: @foobar writefds and readfds only contain sockfd indeed, but later I plan to use a timeout for send and recv later. I'm adding some more previous code to show you how I initialize those variables. Both message and buf are char*, and are same size. Anyway I'm using sizeof(buf) now. Still the code works when the server runs on a virtual machine...

Comment: @DenisDantas: `sizeof(char*) != strlen(char*)`.  You need to stop using `sizeof()`, you are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. you are not resetting `readfds` and `writefds` every time you call `select()`, as it modifies them each time.
2. you are misusing `sizeof()`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
char message[1024];
char buf[1024];
fd_set readfds, writefds;
int numSent, numRead;

memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
strncpy(message, "whatever you need to send...", sizeof(message)-1);

for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &writefds);

    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);

    rvd = select(sockfd+1, NULL, &writefds, NULL, NULL); 
    if (rvd == -1)
        break;

    printf("client: writing '%s'\n", message);
    if ((numSent = send(sockfd, message, strlen(message), 0)) < 1)
        break;

    rvd = select(sockfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (rvd == -1)
        break;

    if ((numRead = recv(sockfd, buf, numSent, 0)) < 1)
        break;

    printf("client: received '%*s'\n", numRead, buf);
}
```

Comment: I now included the FD_ZERO and FD_SET inside the for loop in order to reset readfds and writefds, and I'm also using strlen + numSet to specify the length of the data to send and recv. But the program is still breaking on send() and the same message is being displayed by eclipse on Debug mode.

Comment: Then please update your question with your latest code, including all relevant declarations, especially `message` and `buf`.

Comment: I just did that. Let me know if there's anything still unclear.